# Why is it defined this way in web.xml in JSF?

Tags: cdi, web.xml

In this little project, there is only one class RichBean.java, and a JSF file index.html, to demonstrate the use of CDI in JSF. My question is regarding the "

```
 <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>"
```

defined in web.xml. Why is it "faces/"?

There is no any mentioning of "faces/" directory or configuration. I thought "faces" is just a name that can be anything, but it isn't the case. I tried changing it to something else, i.e. "faceg", it then doesn't work.

RichBean.java

```
    @Named
    @SessionScoped
    public class RichBean implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postContruct() {
        name = "John";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    }
```

index.xhtml

```
....
<body>
<ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">Hello world JSF</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="body">
        <fieldset style="width:500px">
            <legend>Helloworld using JSF and RichFaces</legend>
            <p>
                This example demonstrates adding ajax processing and updating to a standard JSF component.
            </p>

            <rich:panel header="Ajax enabled inputText">
                <h:form id="helloWorldJsf">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Name:" for="nameInput"/>
                    <h:inputText id="nameInput" value="#{richBean.name}">
                        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="output"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:panelGroup id="output">
                        <h:outputText value="Hello #{richBean.name}!"
                                      rendered="#{not empty richBean.name}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:form>
            </rich:panel>
        </fieldset>
    </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
    </body>
    </html>
```

beans.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    </beans>
```

web.xml.

How is "faces/" configured? I have no idea of how and why it's connected to anything else in the proejct.

I am learning this demo. Please help understand this. Thanks a lot.

```
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-    app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- add a welcome-file-list entry to allow JSF pages to be used as welcome files -->
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet class FacesServlet starts the JSF request processing
life cycle and must be defined in the web.xml. The servlet mapping
tag defines the for which URL the FacesServlet should be executed.
The pattern **/faces/*** is commonly used by the JSF specification but
**any other prefix or extension is possible**. The example uses as
web-app attribute version=“2.5” this means we are using 
servlet-api version 2.5. If you use tomcat 6 we need minimum
servlet-api in version 2.5. Compared with jsf 1.2 nothing changed in
this example.
Below you can see the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
<display-name>HelloWorld with JSF RI 2 (Beta 2)</display-name>
<servlet>
<display-name>FacesServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**You can change /faces/ *to /facesg/* as per your requirement and it will work for you.**

I hope it will resolve your query !!

Comment: Why do you use a different web.xml as an example, which is very different from what I gave. So you didn't explain the question well with your example. Please use my web.xml to explain. Thanks.